# jq filter to combine two json values into one with a slash delimiter

Tags: json, jq, string-concatenation

I'm trying to use `jq` to process a json input:

```
{
"foo":"xxx",
"bar":"yyy"
}
```

Trying to get the following desired json output:

`{"path":"xxx/yyy"}`

I've tried several things for the filter, generally

```
.|.foo as $path1|.bar as $path2|{"path":?????}
```

`$path1+"/"+$path2` does not work.

What should I replace ????? with to get desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or just:

```
{"path":(.foo + "/" + .bar)}
```

or perhaps better (in case conversion to strings is needed):

```
{"path": "\(.foo)/\(.bar)"}
```

Comment: Thanks.  My actual problem was a little more complex, but this approach helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

You are really close.  I think you just need some parenthesis:

```
.|.foo as $path1|.bar as $path2|{"path":($path1 + "/" + $path2)}
```

Comment: Wait, what? Why would parens be needed there?! That's messed up.